# Configuring EHCache for Spring3.1.1 and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache

I am attempting to enable object caching in an existing Spring 3.1.1 application with Hibernate 3.5.5. I am using ehcache 2.2.0. In my applicationContext I have added the configuration to switch on caching with EHCache.

```
<cache:annotation-driven />
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"
    p:cache-manager="ehcache" />
<bean id="ehcache"
    class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
    p:config-location="ehcache.xml" />
```

I then created the ehcache.xml file:

```
<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

<defaultCache 
    eternal="false" 
    maxElementsInMemory="1000"
    overflowToDisk="false" 
    diskPersistent="false" 
    timeToIdleSeconds="0"
    timeToLiveSeconds="0" 
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>

<cache name="studentCache" 
    eternal="false"
    maxElementsInMemory="10000" 
    overflowToDisk="false" 
    diskPersistent="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="0" 
    timeToLiveSeconds="0"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
```

I added the necessary dependencies in the pom.xml file for ehcache. But now I am getting this error:

```
Initialization of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: 
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
'net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager' for property 'cacheManager'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type
[net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager] for property 'cacheManager': 
no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Yours should work... here is my working configuration if it helps:

    <cache:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
        <property name="cacheManager"><ref local="ehcache"/></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
          p:configLocation="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>

Comment: @aweigold Thanks. That seem to work for some reason. I was missing the property element. Why don't you add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to reference your cacheManager property differently.  This is how I have it working:

```
<cache:annotation-driven />
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
 <property name="cacheManager"><ref local="ehcache"/></property>
</bean>
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:configLocation="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 12):

@aweigold 's answer is perfect but a clearer solution can be achieved if you pass the reference of "ehcache" bean using "p:cacheManager-ref".

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"
    p:cacheManager-ref="ehcache" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Include the below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The same as in last post only without mistake in attribute name:

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cacheManager-ref="ehcache" />
```